# Errors while deploying chunk files through windows powershell

Tags: powershell, deployment, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to deploy my built code through powershell to SharePoint 2013 but I am getting multiple errors while running the powershell script .

**Set-PnPFileCheckedOut :Method 'GetFileByServerRelativePath" doesn't exist.**

I have gone through multiple sites /questions but none of them work.
Can you suggest a way to make this work.

Comment: Show us the code you used, not just an error.

Comment: The issue was resolved after uninstalling powershell online and installing powershell 2013.